# Lexicographic sort float array python

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, lexicographic

Okay, so, I have a 4x2 numpy ndarray, and I want to sort it lexicographically. That is, if I have the array

```
[[0,0],
[1,1],
[0,1],
[1,0]]
```

I want it to become

```
[[0,0],
[0,1],
[1,0],
[1,1]]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `l.sort()` does the trick for normal lists

Comment: Doesn't seem to be doing it. Going l.sort() turns [[2,1], [0,2]] into [[1,2], [0,2]] instead of [[0,2], [2,1]] (when it's an ndarray).

Comment: `l.sort()` converts `l = [[2,1], [0,2]]` into `[[0, 2], [2, 1]]` only for a normal list and not for an numpy array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use numpy's [`lexsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html).  Lexsort, though, sorts using the last column as the primary key.  One way to get what you want is to specify the columns explicitly:

```
 x[np.lexsort((x[:,1], x[:,0]))]

 # array([[0, 0],
 #   [0, 1],
 #   [1, 0],
 #   [1, 1]])
```

Comment: Do you know what the time complexity of this is?

Comment: @PedroCarvalho: For an h-by-w array, the worst case performance is `O(h*w*log(h))`, since it's a comparison sort on an input of length h where comparisons can take worst-case O(w) time. If rows usually differ in the first few columns, the expected performance will be `O(h*log(h))`, since comparisons will take expected O(1) time.

Comment: Also, rather than listing columns individually, you can do `x[np.lexsort(x.T[::-1])]`. (That's still way too many intermediate steps to just do a lexicographic sort, though. NumPy's sorting API seems to be put together in a really weird way.)